# Counter and accumulator in a java loop

Tags: java

I'm doing this program: Given an integer, n, if the sum of its divisors (not counting itself) equals n, that number is said to be perfect. If the sum is lower, it is said to be decient, and if it is higher it is said to be abundant. For example:

6 has divisors 1,2,3: they add 6, therefore 6 is perfect. 8 has divisors 1,2,4: they add 7, therefore 8 is deciente. 24 has divisors 1,2,3,4,6,8,12: they add 36, therefore 24 is abundant.

Write a program that reads two positive integers and displays, on the screen, how many numbers there are of each type in that interval (including the extremes).

I have the following code and I know where it fails, for example if I enter a single number, I do it well, example of entries 6 and 7. If I then enter 6 and 9 the output is Perfect 1 Deficient 0 Abundant 2, when I should to be Perfect 1 Deficient 2 Abundant 0. Variable j stores the divisors of all in the variable j and then that's why it's abundant but I have not been able to correct it for more than I've tried.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PerfectNumbers {

public static void main(String[] args) {

System.out.println("Enter two numbers for the interval:");
Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
int x = teclado.nextInt();
int y = teclado.nextInt();

int cont1 = 0;
int perfect = 0;
int deficient = 0;
int abundant = 0;

for (int i = x; i < y; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) {

        if (i % j == 0) {

            cont1 += j;
        } else {
            cont1 += 0;
        }

    }
    if (cont1 == x) {
        perfect += 1;
    } else if (cont1 < x) {
        deficient += 1;
    } else if (cont1 > x) {
        abundant += 1;
    }
}

System.out.println("Perfect"+ perfect);
System.out.println("Deficient"+ deficient);
System.out.println("Abundant"+ abundant);
}
}
```

Comment: Besides the bugs already covered by the answers, I'd recommend to refactor the code: to introduce a method that classifies a single number: `private static Classification classifyNumber(int number) { ... }`, returning an `enum Classification {DEFICIENT, PERFECT, ABUNDANT}`. Or if you don't feel comfortable with enums, an int with -1 being "deficient", 0 being "perfect", and 1 being "abundant". Then you can easily use that classification method in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that you didn't reset `cont1`.

Another problem is that instead of comparing to `x` to decide perfect/deficient/abundant, you need to compare to `i`.

```
for (int i = x; i < y; i++) {
    cont1 = 0;
    for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
        if (i % j == 0) {
            cont1 += j;
        }
    }

    if (cont1 == i) {
        perfect += 1;
    } else if (cont1 < i) {
        deficient += 1;
    } else {
        abundant += 1;
    }
}
```

I think the second problem was easy to overlook because of the poor naming of variables. I suggest to improve that, and it will be easier to read and harder to make such mistakes:

```
for (int n = start; n < end; n++) {
    sum = 0;
    for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) {
        if (n % j == 0) {
            sum += j;
        }
    }

    if (sum == n) {
        perfect++;
    } else if (sum < n) {
        deficient++;
    } else {
        abundant++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I already realized that there was another mistake with the other answer they gave me. It is clearer now with start and end